# Facebook: refresh AccessToken on Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication, facebook-sdk-4.0

They are saying in the [AccessToken docu](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending) the following: "Native mobile applications using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed once per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers."
Does it mean that only if the request to Facebook's servers is made from client Android app (I am not sure how to interpret the "... the person using your app ...") then the access token will be refreshed ?
In my app, I retrieve the access token using `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()`, send the access token to my server and the server makes the request to Facebook's servers with the aim to validate the received access token.
Will the access token be refreshed also in that case ? (in that case the server is doing the request to FB's servers and not directly "the person using my app")

- If yes, How does the Facebook SDK in the Android client app knows that my server made the request to Facebook's servers ? Does the`AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` in Android client returns the refreshed access token ?

Thank you

**EDIT**: This may help the others to save time:
I found out that access token is under certain conditions automatically refreshed at initializing the FacebookSDK (Facebook docu doesn't clearly explain how the access token is refreshed - See my question above).
Please notice I am using FacebookSDK 4.0 for Android.
Follow the steps bellow:

1. `FacebookSDK.sdkInitialize(Context, InitializeCallback)`

   `if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null &&                       Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null)`
2. `Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken()`
3. `Utility.getGraphMeRequestWithCacheAsync()`

   `GraphRequest graphRequest = getGraphMeRequestWithCache(accessToken); 
   graphRequest.setCallback(graphCallback);
   graphRequest.executeAsync();`
4. ... `executeBatchAsync(GraphRequestBatch requests)`
   `GraphRequestAsyncTask asyncTask = new GraphRequestAsyncTask(requests);
   asyncTask.executeOnSettingsExecutor();`
5. See `GraphRequestAsyncTask doInBackground()` method

`if (connection == null) {
     return requests.executeAndWait();
 } else {
    return GraphRequest.executeConnectionAndWait(connection, requests);
 }`

For both cases the code will end up in this method:

```
public static List<GraphResponse> executeConnectionAndWait(
            HttpURLConnection connection,
            GraphRequestBatch requests)
```

6. Notice `AccessTokenManager.getInstance().extendAccessTokenIfNeeded();` line.
   Which as the name suggest will extend your access token at most once per day.

Comment: Yes, in that case, the server is making a request to refresh the access token and will receive a new access token. However, the app will not be aware of this. Any subsequent API requests will continue to be made with the old access token and will fail.

Comment: @subeeshb I am not making a request to refresh the access token on the server. I just call a /me .... GRAPH API request. I guess you are not saying that each simple GRAPH API request includes a request to refresh access token.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/) method:

```
AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync();
```

Comment: This will only refresh the expire date if possible. I have checked that the expire date can remain the same after calling this function. That is because now the token expires anyway after 60 days. Then you need to ask the user again to login with Facebook to renew the token.

Comment: But i can't. It failed when called.
Error: Failed to refresh access token.

I'm using facebook test user. Had change password and relogin. Still cannot.

Comment: Dude, this was for old SDK, FB did so many new changes in SDK. I am not sure if it will be working today as well.

Comment: This won't work unless user logged in via facebook app, because they only allow sso tokens to be extended for some reason... If user logged in via browser, token will remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states (emphasis mine):

> When you use the iOS, Android, or JavaScript SDK, the SDK will
> **automatically refresh tokens** if the person has used your app within
> the last 90 days. Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs get
> long-lived User access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens
> are refreshed once per day, when the **person using your app makes a
> request to Facebook's servers**.

What this *means* is that if you use **the official SDK built-in Graph API** client ([`GraphRequest`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/) and friends), then after each request the SDK will [attempt to refresh the token](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/3901993f8cd3ec1fd5b311042f560242b010675c/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/GraphRequest.java#L1255) (but not more often that once a day).

To do so, the SDK uses the undocumented Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/oauth/access_token?access_token={user-access-token}&grant_type=fb_extend_sso_token&client_id={your-app_id}
```

(It's probably available in all Graph API versions, but I haven't tested it)

The Android SDK also exposes this token refreshing functionality directly in the public API with [`refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/) method.

It's very important to note that token refreshing works *only* for so called "SSO" tokens, i.e. those received from the Facebook app. If the user doesn't have the Facebook app installed on their device, or for any other reason the log-in flow used the webview variant, the token received that way **will not ever by refreshed**. As far as I know, this is not documented anywhere.

The undocumented API mentioned above returns a `400` error when you attempt to refreshed the token received from the webview flow:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
{"error":{"message":"(#10) The access token was not obtained using single sign-on","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"AbGFcwx4aOhY0sgEkLdAR34"}}
```

This whole answer is written with Android in mind, but I assume that it applies to iOS SDK as well (but I haven't tested that).

Comment: Thanks for this little nugget. I've just spend hours looking through our apps auth code on start-up trying to figure why a small % of Android users get logged out after an extended period of time but not all. Basically if they use Webview their session will expire after 60 days and the only recourse is for them to login again. Doh - be nice if FB documented this 'feature' somewhere!